# Notice: Undefined offset: 0 - My array contains values

Tags: php, arrays, odbc

I have a little problem, I don't understand.

I have this code :

```
public function formAlreadySent($demande){
        $data = odbc_exec($this->dbConnection,"SELECT COUNT(*) FROM [@JDC_QSTR] WHERE U_Demande = ".$demande);
        $nombre = odbc_fetch_array($data);
        print_r($nombre);
        if($nombre[0] > 0)
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }
```

The result of my `print_r` is :

> Array ( [0] => 0 )

But I got this error :

> Notice: Undefined offset: 0 in C:\wamp\www\enquetesatisfaction\libs\model\QuestionsManager.class.php on line 89

Line 89 is :

```
if($nombre[0] > 0)
```

If someone know why this problem happen ?

Thanks in advance !

Comment: check odbc_num_rows. How many rows does the query returns?

Comment: Is it possible this method is called more than once? What is the value of `$demande`? Is it guaranteed to be an integer value?

Comment: It is not an error, it's just a message that is shown. A notice is a message for saying what you should do and what you should not do.

Comment: @KurtVandenBranden So if I understand, I should not do read a value in an array that contain only one row ?

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski I call my method only once and $demande is an integer value

Comment: can you please `var_dump($nombre)`

Comment: @JigarShah var_dump return this : `array (size=1)
  '0' => string '0' (length=1)`

Comment: check echo $nombre[0].

Comment: @ThomasRollet Try `$nombre['0']` instead of `$nombre[0]`

Comment: As stated by Gunaseelan, you're assuming that `$nombre[0]` has an element.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the PHP documentation, `odbc_fetch_array` fetches a result row and returns it as an associative array, or returns `false` if there are no more rows.

Being an *associative* array, the index of the first item (`COUNT(*)`) should not be `[0]`. To be honest, I don't know why it apparently is.

I would suggest this: first alias the count in your SQL, like

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS rowcount ...
```

Then reference that alias after you fetch the result.

```
if($nombre['rowcount'] > 0) ...
```

Answer (score 1):

as per the `var_dump` output:

```
array (size=1) '0' => string '0' (length=1)
```

The reason for error

> Notice: Undefined offset: 0 in

is that it is a `string` and you are accessing as an `integer`

It can be stooped using `if` with key but I would suggest to check using PHP funciton [array_key_exists](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-key-exists.php)